# Find all ring morphisms from $\Bbb Z^n$ to $\Bbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I tested the case where $n=1$ and I found that there exist just one homomorphism which the idendity.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb Z^n\to\mathbb Z?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A ring homomorphism is a linear map over $\Bbb Z$ so it is given by multiplication by a $1\times n$ integer matrix $A$. Being a ring homomorphism means that for every two vectors $u,v$ of dim $n$ we have $A(u\circ v)= (Au)(Av)$ where $\circ$ is the coordinate-wise product of vectors.

Let $A=(a_1,...,a_n)$. Take $u=v=e_i$ (the $i$-th basic vector. Then $a_i=a_ia_i$. So each coordinate of $A$ is $ 0 $ or $1$. Then take $u=v=(1,1,...,1)^T$. Then $(\sum a_i)^2=(\sum a_i)$. So among coordinates of $A$ there are at most $1$ coordinate $1$ and the rest are $0$. There are $n+1$ such vectors $A$ and all of them work.

**Answer:** all homomorphisms are either $0$ (maps everything to $0$) or $v\mapsto e_i^T v$, $i=1,...,n$.

Comment: Well, if by ring homomorphism we also mean to preserve the identity element, then the constant zero map is out of the game. Note also that the rest are just the coordinate projections $v\mapsto v_i$.

Comment: @JCAA I'm not one to talk about not being opinionated about definitions on occasion, but you're coming across a little rude. Different people work in different areas of math. In some of those areas unital rings have primary importance, and in others, the theory would be incomplete without nonunital rings. Describing algebra textbooks as "sub-par" because they make a different decision than you do comes across as somewhat rude, but putting the word experts in quotation marks definitely comes across as rude and insulting to people who put time in to answer questions on this site.

Comment: @jgon: Your comment is not about my answer. It is impolite and contains false information. If you do not understand the answer, ask a question.

Comment: @JCAA Given that you've deleted the comment that I was replying to, I'll assume that you figured out that I was replying to your comment rather than to your answer. I tried to be careful to put my reply as politely as possible, and did not assume you meant to be rude. I certainly do not think that my comment "contains false information." Ordinarily, I would delete my comment after it ceased to be relevant, when you deleted your first comment, but your reply convinces me that my first comment does in fact remain relevant.

Comment: @jgon: You keep commenting my answer. Your comments are impolite and misleading. Give your own answer if you can come up with something better.